# Log4j - missing logs in zipped files under heavy load

Tags: java, logging, log4j

**We are encountering problem with log4j logging under heavy logging.**
We periodically miss some logs (~4-20 minutes each 1 hour) in files, that are rolled out and zipped.

Configuration:

```
<appender name="MY_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender">
    <param name="File"   value="../logs/mylog.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="40MB"/>
    <param name="MaxRollFileCount" value="100"/>
    <param name="ScavengeInterval" value="300000"/>
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="CompressionAlgorithm" value="ZIP"/>
    <param name="CompressionMinQueueSize" value="5"/>
    <param name="CompressionThreadPriority" value="1"/>
    <param name="CompressionLevel" value="1"/>
    <param name="CompressionUseBlockingQueue" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %22.22t| %22.22c{1}| %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Property `<param name="CompressionUseBlockingQueue" value="true"/>` was added as attempt to prevent logs from getting lost. We thought (and we still do) that logs get lost while files (when there is 5 temp files) are merged and zipped. That they might get overwritten somehow. However, this property didn't work.

I'm not sure where to look for problem, or how to change configuration, so logs wouldn't get lost, or overwritten.

Any suggestions what we might try?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a copy of the log to some temp location (or at the same location, if space is not a constraint); and then zip it.

It might happen that the point of time zipping is happening, the logger buffer is trying to wrte back and faling. Since log4j fails silently, it is difficult to trace such error.

Comment: We'll try it with "<param name="CompressionMinQueueSize" value="1"/>", perhaps that will help although I don't think so. Isn't there a way how to enable some kind of log4j failure notifications? Or could we try to monitor it via JMX, if there's some useful info there.

Comment: The error in log4j usually caught through server log files. You may want to put a monitor like Tivoli monitor on the log files with specific keywords. The reason for log4j failure is suppressed because any app should not crash on failure of writing a log file.